# How can I stop the Powershell command `Get-NetFirewallRule` from throwing an error?

Tags: powershell, firewall

I'm trying to determine if a firewall rule exists or not, with Powershell.

If the rule does *not* exist, I get an ugly error message. If it does exist, all is good :)

How can I check if the rule exists without any ugly red error message occuring?

eg.

```
Import-Module NetSecurity

# Check if the firewall rule exists.
$existingRule = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $name
```

Error message (when the rule doesn't exist)...

```
Get-NetFirewallRule : No MSFT_NetFirewallRule objects found with property 'DisplayName' equal to 'Blah Blah Port 44444'.  Verify the value of the property and retry. At C:\projects\xwing\Setup.ps1:67 char:21
+     $existingRule = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $name
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Blah Blah Port 44444:String) [Get-NetFirewallRule], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DisplayName,Get-NetFirewallRule
```

Anyone know how to safely check for a rule, please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Populate the `-ErrorAction` parameter for the cmdlet

`Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

At this point you can test the result of the last command using `$?`. If the rule exists, this will return `$true`.

Alternatively, you can use a try / catch block:

```
try {
  Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName blah -ErrorAction Stop
  Write-Host "Rule found"
}
  catch [Exception] {
  write-host $_.Exception.message
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've never seen that param before (I just started learning it today). Does that `-ErrorAction` cmdlet param exist for basically all `Get-XXX` cmdlets?

Comment: It exists on **all** cmdlets as far as I know. If you type `Get-Help about_CommonParameters` into a PowerShell console that'll bring up the list of parameters that exist everywhere.

Comment: Thank you kindly @arco444 - i really appreciated your help :) .. Time to ask one last PS question (in a new SO question)...

Comment: Just in case you want to do the same with a command that is not a cmdlet, you can set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `"SilentlyContinue"` prior to executing your command. Once the command is executed, you can set it back to `Continue`